# Laravel 5.8 error trying to get the 'id' property of non-object

Tags: laravel

I'm developing an application with Laravel 5.8. In my application, I have a controller that handles backend articles, and it works. I want to display my user-side information in such a way that a user can click on a link and see the detail of an article. For that, I have created a new controller a with a new namespace for the function show my redirection of navigation in different page does not focus that it is en route or URL with Laravel 5.8. Below is the function.

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Cybernaut;

use App\History;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class HistoryController extends Controller
{
    public function show($id)
    {
        $history = History::find($id);

        return view('show_history', compact('history'));
    }
}
```

At the level of the home page I wanted to have my links like these:

```
   <li><a data-hover="history"  href="{{route('history.show',$history→id)}}"><span>history</span></a></li>
```

**Error**

> ErrorException (E_ERROR) Property [id] does not exist on this
>   collection instance. (View:
>   C:\laragon\www\venome\resources\views\layouts\partial\header.blade.php)

And here is the route used for the show function.

```
Route::group(['namespace'=>'cybernaut'], function (){
    Route::get('/history/{slug}','HistoryController@show')->name('history.show');
});
```

Try after modifying the thing I have these at the route level now.

```php
Route::get('/', 'FrontController@index')->name('index');
Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::get('/admin/dashboard', 'DashboardController@index')->name('admin.dashboard');
Route::group([], function () {
    Route::get('/history', 'HistoryController@index')->name('history.index');
    Route::get('/history', 'HistoryController@create')->name('history.create');
    Route::get('/history/edit', 'HistoryController@update')->name('history.update');
    Route::get('/history', 'HistoryController@destroy')->name('history.destroy');
});

Route::group(['namespace' => 'cybernaut'], function () {
    Route::get('/history/{history}', [
        'as' => 'show',
        'uses' => 'HistoryController@show'
    ]);
});
```

At the level of the homepage I wanted to put my link like those here now;

```php
@foreach($history as $history)
    <li><a data-hover="history" href="{{url('/history/'.$history->id)}}"><span>history</span></a></li>
@endforeach
```

I have this error now:

> Trying to get property 'id' of non-object (View:
>   C:\laragon\www\venome\resources\views\layouts\partial\header.blade.php)

I want an internaut to be able to navigate between the pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a conflict of variables on your homepage.

```
@foreach($history as $history)
```

should be

```
@foreach($histories as $history)
```

where $histories is filled in in your FrontController.

```
$histories = History::all();
```

When actually getting your single history object, I agree with Sapnesh's answer that you best doublecheck whether or not the object actually exists.

Answer (score 0):

#### The error occurs because `find()` returns NULL when a model is not found.

> find($id) takes an id and returns a single model. If no matching model
>   exist, it returns null.
>
> findOrFail($id) takes an id and returns a single model. If no matching
>   model exists, it throws an error.

In your `show()` method,

**Change:**

```
    $history = History::find($id);
```

**To:**

```
    $history = History::findOrFail($id);
```